# Is it possible to run a command when the makefile finishes without an external script?

Tags: makefile

I would like to run `@echo "Make complete."` When the makefile finishes running. The problem is I can't figure out a way for it to do that without putting it at the end of of every option, but I wouldn't like to do that since for example the `all` option would echo "Make complete." multiple times. I also know I could run a script such as:

```
make $1
echo "Make complete."
```

But that solution is messy because it uses 2 files and it wouldn't work if the user didn't type an argument. 
I am using GNU Make.

Comment: No, there is no way to run a "final command" without playing tricks with recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a wrapper makefile calling the real makefile:

```
$(MAKECMDGOALS):
    $(MAKE) -f makefile.real $@
    @echo "Make complete."
```

There are caveats and some extra things that need doing to handle multiple targets and passing on the environment and other options, which I'm sure the SO community will add as comments to this answer.

Comment: Just to note you should _always_ use the variable `$(MAKE)` (or `${MAKE}`, same thing) and _never_ use the bare value `make` when invoking make recursively.

Comment: You can also do this all within a single makefile, if you add a big `ifdef / else / endif` around most of it so that if some internal variable is not set make invokes itself recursively and sets that internal variable, and if it is set you use the "real" makefile.

Comment: @MadScientist Edited. (I must be getting rusty.)